# "unexpected keyword argument 'version'" when trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
2022-02-06T22:55:19.786956+00:00 app[web.1]:

Error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

2022-02-06T22:55:19.959506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-06T22:55:20.021043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-06T22:55:20.033987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-06T22:55:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-02-06T22:55:27.937148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn bona_blog.wsgi:application --log-file -`
2022-02-06T22:55:30.108106+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-06T22:55:30.108127+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
2022-02-06T22:55:30.316169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-06T22:55:30.440121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-06T22:56:11.005567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fceoapp.herokuapp.com request_id=45757802-6d06-4d6e-80d3-90feafdeb023 fwd="105.112.52.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-06T22:56:10.341541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fceoapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c030a659-ad28-4088-8b87-58d94731a394 fwd="105.112.52.76" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider including the code in question and not just the error.

Comment: I have about 20 different scripts in the django app don't even Know which to include 

Comment: Heroku complained of an unexpected keyword "version". I have searched all the scripts present in the app nothing like version. I don't know what to do